# CMake optimizing out values in debug mode

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to view some simple int variables in GDB, but they're all being marked as "value optimized out". At the top of my CMakeLists.txt file, I have

```
set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
```

Do I need to set something else?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99536/cmake-optimizing-out-values-in-debug-mode/) by [vhwanger](https://answers.ros.org/users/3648/vhwanger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2013-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to recompile what the section of code that you are running.  And if you're inside a library you need to recompile that library. (What you have noted is correct for rosbuild based packages.)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vhwanger](https://answers.ros.org/users/3648/vhwanger/) on 2013-11-12**:
This is actually after a make clean and rosmake.